# Proguard rules for accessing IInAppBillingService method with reflection

Tags: android, proguard, in-app-billing

I have the following code in my Android project:

```
Class<?> iabServiceStubClass = Class.forName("com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub");
asInterfaceMethod = iabServiceStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
```

At runtime, I am getting the exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: asInterface [interface android.os.IBinder]
```

Any suggestions for what proguard rules to use to fix this problem?
I have tried the following:

```
-keep public class com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService {
    public static com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService asInterface(android.os.IBinder);
    public android.os.Bundle getSkuDetails(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle);
}
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.android.vending.billing.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently had to debug Facebook SDK for a problem regarding auto logging purchases. See [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook-core/src/main/java/com/facebook/appevents/internal/InAppPurchaseEventManager.java) how they access the method. Look for IN_APP_BILLING_SERVICE_STUB.

Also use in your Proguard file 
`-keep class com.android.vending.billing.** { *; }`

Comment: That's similar to the proguard rule that ended up working for me.  In this particular case I had to use: `-keep class * implements com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService { *; }`